# How do I open a URL with a custom scheme in Yosemite with cron and open?

Tags: command-line, cron

I had a cron job that ran every morning at 10:30 to call into our daily status meeting on Go2Meeting. After I upgraded to Yosemite it stopped working, and I figured out that it was because

```
open -g citrixonline://blahblahblah
```

now sees the URL as a file name, and not a URL with a custom scheme. Can I get `open` to treat this like a URL again?

Comment: For now the workaround is to open the web page that redirects to the custom URL. Probably Go2Meeting would prefer that I do that anyway. Still, it would be nice to open custom URLS from `open`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if opening the URL scheme via Safari would help?

```
open -g /Applications/Safari.app citrixonline://blahblah; killall Safari
```